# qemu: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists

Tags: qemu

I am trying to enable trace events using the trace-file on option in qemu.
When I executed the following command: 
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-box1-vm-disk1-5G ./build/trace/trace-events-all on`
it shows the following:
`qemu-system-x86_64: ./build/trace/trace-events-all: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists` 
I tried change the index by adding `index=1,media=disk`
but it still doesn't work.